# changing vim's vertsplit character to │

Tags: vim

This is, I assume, codepage related, but doesn't hurt asking.

How would one, on windows xp's cmd, gvim 7.2 change vertsplit character, so that instead of default | it is │ (so that it makes a full, and not an splitted line) ?

That character is usually changed with

```
set fillchars=vert:\|
```

and I can copy paste the ascii graphics line there, but it comes out as garbage. I suppose I would have to change vim's internal codepage for it to show correctly ?

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I'm really late to the party but this is what I do.

The way the characters are rendered depends on the font so you can get a continuous line using some fonts and not with others. I've found that using one of the following gives me an unbroken line.

- Menlo
- Monaco
- Inconsolata
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Consolas
- Bitstream Vera Sans Mono

As far as settings go, the following is sufficient. Note that this is different from the | character commonly present on keyboards.

```
set fillchars=vert:\│
```

Comment: Better late than never tim! :) You've certanly provided me with a few interesting bits - gimme an ascii/unicode value what is that other vertical line character, and I'm assigning this answer as correct!

Comment: You can copy-paste it and it will work. However, pressing `ga` in vim dumps this `<│> 9474, Hex 2502, Octal 22402`

Answer (score 7):

I've tried the following :

```
set enc=utf-8
set fillchars=vert:\│
```

And it worked, but the result weren't has good as you can hope, it's still not a full line (using the Consolas font, if you get a straight line with another font, I'd be interested to know which one).

Comment: Well, so far I've only gotten a straight line in cmd, meaning I can get it using "raster fonts" and "lucida console". But I'm sure other fonts have those characters, it's just that I cannot get the codepage to display them. B

Comment: Also, when you said you got a not-full-line. Are you sure you're using the box character and not the vertical line ?

Comment: Yep, I've seen an improvement, but it's still not connected.

Comment: In an attempt to solve this ... if I understood correctly "set encoding" takes care of vim's internal encoding. But although I can change it, I cannot find a codepage which syncs so it fits with what cmd uses (and I don't know what cmd uses :(

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using gvim, vim inside cmd is too clunky for me.

Comment: I get a straight line in gvim using Liberation Mono as long as I `:set linespace=0`. I suspect your air gap is coming from having extra space between lines, not the character you are drawing in each line. On the other hand gvim is the one that's too clunky for me, and I prefer the terminal in most cases. Are you sure you know how to configure your terminal? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you want, but I've `set fillchars=\` and just use highlighting to color the blank space a different color.  It's less elegant, but it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Digging through the digraph table, I found that the "Box drawings light vertical" is perfect for this purpose. Vim's digraph table entry:

`│       vv      2502    9474    BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL`

To use it, press `<c-k>vv` in insert or command mode to get the character (see `:h i_CTRL-K`).
As pointed out by others, the setting is applied with `set fillchars=vert:|`

Comment: How do I use it, how do I get it in Vim? I tried copy paste but it didn't work.

Comment: Changed the post to reflect usage :)

Comment: btw, I've found `:h digraph-table` useful on multiple occasions when I've wanted to locate a special character