# How to change color of border in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, border, nerdtree

**How to change color of border in NERDTree to be transparent?**

Comment: Are you looking for `'fillchars'`? See `:h 'fillchars'`. Or [changing vim's vertsplit character to |](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269287/changing-vims-vertsplit-character-to-%e2%94%82)

Comment: @peter I see,but I want to change the color of border,don't display the color

Answer (score 5):

This should be fairly straightforward. The NERDTree plugin gets its colour settings globally. So adding something like this in your .vimrc file should do the trick:

```
highlight VertSplit ctermbg=NONE
highlight VertSplit ctermfg=NONE
```

Just a heads up though - this will change the settings for everything that uses the VertSplit such as split windows etc. If this isn't what you want then perhaps try disabling only the background (ctermbg). These are commands for the terminal version as well so if you have a gui then it would be guifg=NONE and guibg=NONE (I think).

Edit: Also make sure that you have the line `Syntax enable` in your .vimrc too.

Comment: :Sorry,it can't work,the color still dispalay.When I change to other color,it can be worked,but cann't be transparent.

Comment: Have you tried setting them to NONE instead of another colour?

Comment: But when I setting them to `highlight VertSplit cterm=NONE`.That's OK.I don't know why?

Comment: Hmm, OK. Out of interest do you set the 'term' variable anywhere in your .vimrc? Something like 'set term='?